# How do I run a script when user clicks on switch user option in Linux?

Tags: bash, shell

I wrote  one script

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p /home/xyz/pppp
```

I want to run this **script**  at the time of user **click on** the option of **switch user**, which is at the top right corner of  my **Linux desktop** .

- What should I do?

Comment: Please provide what you tried to solve this problem

Comment: @PeterStaranchuk  i am trying to run this script from the path /etc/profile. also i  tried  to run this script from  /etc/X11/*  directory but it is not working .

Comment: Lots of information missing. E.g.: which window manager / desktop are you using?

Comment: This is more of a GNOME/KDE question than a programming question. Try asking at https://unix.stackexchange.com/, https://askubuntu.com/, or https://superuser.com/ instead.

Comment: @FelixKling  i am using GNOME . But i have to run this script for GNOME and KDM also.